# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting blogs
- helpful resources on the subject matter
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/4313).

Comment: I think this is pretty broken, I put in an Imagur link (copied the URL from area51) and it was just a broken link, then I edited it to use the actual PNG file from area51 and that worked.  So... something is screwy...

Comment: This particular post is now obsolete.  See: [Community Promotion Ads - 2016](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/5856/21576)

Answer (score 9):

[image: For those interested in exegetical analysis of biblical texts.]

Comment: Do you have a template/source file for this? Perhaps we could have one saying "Like to discuss matters of truth? Join our chat room"

Comment: @curiousdannii That's a pretty good idea. Let me see what I can come up with. Basically, I'm thinking I'll just change the bible icon to something that implies chat. Perhaps a chat message box with a cross in it. I get the point of the message, but maybe the words should be different. Just tossing around ideas.

Comment: @curiousdannii [I have these two photoshop documents in a zip file on my dropbox.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92136005/C.SE_stock_ad.zip)

Comment: yeah there is probably better wording

Comment: Would using a cross in the image be appropriate for BH? Such would encourage a perception that it is specially about *Christian* hermeneutics when (I thought) BH was intended to include Jewish perspectives.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Yes, that's true, but the people seeing it here are already interested in Christianity, so it makes sense that it looks like a christian bible.

Comment: @fredsbend I am not sure, mainly because I read some complaints about the Christian bias of BH. Encouraging people to go there with a conception that it is Christian seems likely to increase that bias. (I realize that such is a subtle causation at most, but I also think the issue could be avoided relatively easily.)

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton As you know, we have the same problem here. I'm open to suggestions, instead of a cross. I might be able to get the words "Holy Bible" or just "Bible" across it, but that issues the same problem. The word "Bible" is largely a Christian term.

Answer (score 7):

[image: For fun, casual, and sometimes deep conversations about Christianity]

Comment: Alternative based on the wording by @fredsbend. I prefer my original... this is too wordy IMO.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Greek Language]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Hebrew Language]

Answer (score 7):

[image: A question and answer site for enthusiasts and scholars of mythology.]

Comment: If you object to this ad, please let me know in comments.

Comment: I think this needs updating to a 300px wide format. Check the new regs...

Comment: @Caleb Yes, but I'm confused, because this and other size-outdated ads are all over SE. So I'm like "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Comment: It's broke. This post is obsolete and the [2016 version](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/5856/30) isn't accepting anything that's the wrong dimensions. SE staff has been deleting ones that don't match. This ad won't show up anywhere on our site until we have one the proper size and it get's reposted in the 2016 thread.

Comment: @Caleb That went pretty fast: [Community Promotion Ads - 2016](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/5927)

Comment: @Caleb But you can see that the old one is still showing up. [I just snapped this 2 minutes ago.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb3rt.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Latin Language]

Answer (score 6):

[Current Christianity Stack Exchange bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/christianity.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: This is a dynamic ad by Kyle Cronin, which [displays the current number of bounties](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1521) when applicable, and displays [a message encouraging users to post bounties](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225142/266429) otherwise.

Comment: Very nice. Neat way to get people to use that feature more often.

Answer (score 3):

[image: YouVersion - the Bible is everywhere]

Comment: You don't have a vested interest in YouVersion, do you? Not that it really matters. It's a good app. I've used it before. Just in the interest of full disclosure.

Comment: Nope. I don't even have it installed, but it seems pretty popular, and having so many languages is great!

Answer (score 3):

[image: For fun, casual, and sometimes deep conversations about Christianity]

Comment: The purpose of this ad is to try to direct some people wanting to ask truth questions to the chat room instead. If you can think of better wording then please suggest it, I can easily change it and update the ad.

Comment: I like the icon. Good choice. Perhaps a little cross in the chat bubble to the left would be neat. Yes, I think a better saying is there somewhere. Perhaps something that stresses that things that are off-topic for the site are okay in chat and there's plenty of us there willing to talk about them. Perhaps "Everything about Christianity is on-topic in Chat. Join us for regular discussions." and the tool-tip would say "For fun, casual, and sometimes deep conversations about Christianity."

Comment: I have a few concerns about the usefulness of this ad. First, SE users need 20 rep to chat, though, so brand new users might be frustrated after clicking. The same goes for anonymous users who are not registered. Also, the ads seem to only appear on the home page, not the question pages or the main question list pages. I think that's kind of stupid, but that seems to be by design. So the only people who see these ads anyway are mostly unregistered, brand new users. Maybe this is incorrect though.

Comment: @fredsbendtheGrinch I had had similar thoughts. But there are still several people who get to 20 rep and post bad questions, and those with the association bonus would be able to join chat immediately. The ads do show up on question pages though, I just saw yours. I'll make a new ad with your wording seeing as it's very different and no one else has replied saying which they prefer.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: I would like to build an ad based off of this one. What are the fonts being used?

Comment: That's a very good question. I'll try to figure that out for you.

Comment: I think I found it: [Harabara Mais](http://www.dafont.com/harabara.font) It has some effects on it too, I think, so it doesn't look exact, but I think I have something now. Thank you.

Comment: So the ad I made got 6 upvotes. When will it begin showing on the main site?

Comment: @fredsbendtheGrinch I just saw it! :)

Comment: @curiousdannii I just did as well. Cool.