# I, as a teenager, have a website that will help missionaries is a unique way

Tags: discussion

Because this website deals with the topic of Christianity, it can be presumed that there are at least a few Christians on here and, assuming even more, they know a missionary. 
I as a teenager have made a website that creates blogs for missionaries for free (yeah I know it sounds spammy) I am having a hard time getting it off the ground, and I was wondering if I could answer my own question of "Where can I as a missionary get a website?" with my answer of "You can get one here!" and have [my website](http://www.mastermissions.com).

This does have to do with Christianity because it deals with a Christian principle/command, the Great Commission.

Comment: Lots of missionaries use wordpress or blogger. I'm not sure how much more is needed.

Comment: I've created a chat room to give you some feedback about your website. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/22800/mastermissions-website?tab=general

Comment: @DJClayworth excellent. thank you.

Comment: [Another user in chat has a similar thing as well.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22796586#22796586)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, certainly not, because that question would be off-topic. It is about building websites and is a product recommendation type question, which other sites have found problematic, so I doubt this site would go for them.

Perhaps you can build a community ad: [Community Promotion Ads - 2015](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4313/community-promotion-ads-2015)

I actually just looked at your site only a few minutes ago. I would like to vote for your community ad, if you make one, but I didn't see a portfolio. Essentially, there's nothing there to show that you know how to make a blog site. If there was some proof that you know how to make a blog and make it look good, I would upvote your community ad.

Comment: oh, ok. Thanks for the info! and that website is an example of what I can do. It's a modified blog.

Comment: @mastermissions.com Well, it is nice. But you need a portfolio (i.e. at least a handful of sites that you made, even if they are not for real clients). You can put them in a `/portfolio/` folder so you don't have to buy and maintain a bunch of domains. Also, you need to fill matermissions.com with more content. I know you just started, but this is what will lead you to success. Also, you might get some real clients by asking around at your local churches. *Free* is a very attractive price, but people tend to recall that old axiom: You get what you pay for.

Comment: ok. I will make a portfolio.

Answer (score 7):

From the [help center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/behavior):

> **Avoid overt self-promotion.**
>
> The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.
>
> If a large percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; [contact our ad sales team](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact) for details. We also offer [free community promotion ads](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) for open source projects and non-profit organizations.

In addition, I don't think the question you are proposing is a [good fit for this site](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Question that ask how to do something "as a Christian" aren't the same as asking about Christianity in it's various forms.